# Debian Live 3.x with encrypted root filesystem

Tags: debian, encryption, livecd

I'd like to build a Debian Live system based on `sid` with an encrypted root filesystem. It's quite easy to install a Debian system with a rootfs encrypted with dm-crypt/LUKS, so I suppose it's also doable on a live system.

In Debian Live 2.x, `lh_config` used to support an `--encryption` parameter which would do just that, but it's been removed in version 3.x, presumably because `loop-aes` has more-or-less been dropped from more recent version of Debian.

I'm looking to do this because I'm booting the live system from PXE (with the help the `fetch` boot parameter) and would like to make sure it's used only by IT staff, as it contains sensitive information.

As an alternative, I've looked into using an encrypted persistence image, which seems to be better supported in Debian Live, but couldn't figure out how I could load it remotely instead of being looked for on local media.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've sent [a patch for version 4.x](https://lists.debian.org/debian-live/2014/05/msg00039.html) to the Debian Live developpers as a starting point to implement this.